# How to use instances of a module with instances' index?

Tags: specman

For example,

module MM;

MM mm[128]();

I want to get mm[i].signle1,i from 0 to 120.
but I cannot use "for", and I do not want to write 120 statments.

what can I do?

Comment: Are you talking about Specman ports?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of ports and you *can* use a for loop:

```
signals : list of simple_port of bit is instance;
keep signals.size() == 128;
keep for each (s) in signals {
    s.hdl_path() == append("mm[",dec(i),"].signal1");
};
```